# I want to get all the weeks in a year with the start and end working day date for each week in java starting at current date?

Tags: java, controller, calendar

**Example**

As per today's date `24 june 2019` (which is week 24 in a year) then it should show the below details.

```
data:[
 week:24
 {
 startDate:24-06-2019,
 endDate: 28-06-2019
},
week: 25 
{
  startDate: 01-07-2019,
  endDate: 05-07-2019
}
```

Similar data for one year. How can I achieve this data in java. As I am new to java I am struggling to solve this issue. Please help with your explanation or code if possible.

PS: There are 53 weeks in a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would perform this with a good old loop :

```
public void workingDayOfYear() {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, 6, 24); // Java 8 date
    int initialWeekOfyear = date.get(WeekFields.of(Locale.UK).weekOfWeekBasedYear());
    int weekOfYear = initialWeekOfyear;
    do {
        LocalDate firstDayOfWeek = date.with(WeekFields.of(Locale.UK).dayOfWeek(), 1L);
        LocalDate lastWorkingDayOfWeek = date.with(WeekFields.of(Locale.UK).dayOfWeek(), 5L);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Week : ");
        result.append(weekOfYear);
        result.append(", start=");
        result.append(firstDayOfWeek);
        result.append(", end=");
        result.append(lastWorkingDayOfWeek);

        System.out.println(result.toString());
        date = date.plusWeeks(1);
    } while ((weekOfYear = date.get(WeekFields.of(Locale.UK).weekOfWeekBasedYear())) != initialWeekOfyear);
}
```

Output:

> Week : 26, start=2019-06-24, end=2019-06-28
>
> Week : 27, start=2019-07-01, end=2019-07-05
>
> ...
>
> Week : 24, start=2020-06-08, end=2020-06-12
>
> Week : 25, start=2020-06-15, end=2020-06-19

Notice that the 53rd week you need is in fact the first week of 2020.

Comment: yes this works well. Thanks you but i want to display for whole one year i.e till 2020-6-24. what do you advise for that ?

Comment: @Aaseek I modified my code, note that a complete year doesn't include the week #26 of the next year, otherwise it would be a year + 1 week.